# Editing Product in Catalog logs out admin user in Magento 2.4.2

Tags: magento2.4

We are running on Magento 2.4.2 with nginx in frontend. admin user gets logged out when we try to edit any product in Catalog.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: check error log in file and also try to increase admin session lifetime

Comment: hi @GohilRajesh thanks for the update. We have set admin session lifetime to 30000 seconds.

Comment: admin session lifetime to 30000 seconds. -> still issue? and found anything in log?

Comment: Anything found into magento log files for this actions?

Comment: @Gopal were you able to fix the issue, we're having it too ?